# Install Latest OS X version with Internet Recovery

Tags: install, internet-recovery

This is on a 2012 MacBook Air.

I just used Disk Utility and erased the SSD, booted into Internet Recovery, connected to the network and let it do its thing. Its prompting me to install Lion. From this point, how can I perform a fresh install of 10.9.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Mavericks recovery partition? Or is Internet Recovery your only option?

From *OS X: About OS X Recovery*

- If you use the Recovery System stored on your startup disk to reinstall OS X, it installs the most recent version of OS X previously installed on this computer.
- If you use Internet Recovery to reinstall OS X, it **installs the version of OS X that originally came with your computer**. After installation is finished, use the Mac App Store to install related updates or later versions of OS X that you have previously purchased.

[Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718)

---

To reinstall Mavericks, you can either [create Mavericks recovery media](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/) or install Lion and upgrade to Mavericks.